# Playing local audio file from local .json dinamically in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to play local audio files on my app.
I have linked the sounds with a relative path in my local json file, and passed the object in the component.

```js
"audio": "./audio/Lite Saturation - Nostalgia.mp3"
```

I have this function, which works with a relative path with require() (only on browser though), but doesn't work with a dynamic variable.

```js
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const { title, artist, artwork, audio } = tune;

 const handlePlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const sound = new Audio.Sound();
      await sound.loadAsync({ uri: audio });
      await sound.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error playing audio:", error);
    }
  };
```

the console.log({ uri: audio }); shows Object { uri: "./audio/Lite Saturation - Nostalgia.mp3" }
I get an error:

```bash
HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:19006/audio/Lite%20Saturation%20-%20Nostalgia.mp3 failed. localhost:19006
Error playing audio: DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable. TuneDetails.js:27
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: text/html
```

I tried `ReactPlayer`, but got a similar problem.

I don't know, if it is a small mistake or I should use something completely different.
Maybe some other library? I just need to play (and pause) the sound and I need it to work on android, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your audio into the `assets` folder and use `Audio.Sound.createAsync` function:

```js
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

...
const playSound = async () => {
 try {
   const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      require('../../../assets/audio/Lite Saturation - Nostalgia.mp3')
   );
   await sound.playAsync();
 } catch (error: any) {
  // handle error
 }
};
```

Comment: thank you, this actually works on Android as well, but my main problem is that I have multiple data I have to loop over, it is not a single sound, that's why I have the path in a json file and am accessing the file through props. I tried putting the audio files is separate folder and using require(`../assets/audio/${id}.mp3`), which is a very sloppy solution, but doesn't work anyway, because apparently react native doesn't accept template literals.